# How to indent and outdent on line beginning and end with Flutter TextFormField

Tags: string, flutter, dart

I am using a Flutter TextFormField Component to capture some multiline text. I would like to process that text string by breaking it down into a list of words using the following.

```
List<String> splitText = text.split(' ');
```

However, I realised that **if the user returns to the next line down the split by space doesn't work anymore and the last word on the line and first word on the next line are considered a single word.**

If I can detect the last word on the line and first work in a line and indent/outdent with a space, my issue is solved, but I don't know how to detect end and start of lines in a textFormForm

I came up with one option which is probably not ideal, but maybe someone can comment.

Convert the String to runes, then look for the return rune (10) and add the space rune (32) before and after for good measure. Problem is I still need to figure out how to convert it back.

```
    List<int> inputTextRunes = text.runes as List;
    List<int> outputTextInRunes = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < inputTextRunes.length; i++) {
      outputTextInRunes.add(inputTextRunes[i]);
      if (inputTextRunes[i] == 10) {
        outputTextInRunes.insert(i - 1, 32);
        outputTextInRunes.insert(i + 1, 32);
      }
    }

String outputText = String.fromCharCodes(outputTextInRunes);
```

> **Question:**   How to indent and outdent on line beginning and line end
> within Flutter TextFormField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just perform the original `split` targeting more than just space. In this instance, you could use a regular expression that matches all forms of whitespace, including tab characters or newlines.

```dart
List<String> splitText = text.split(RegExp(r'\s'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this works but also removes the returns so the paragraph structure isn't retained as I am overriding the buildTextSpan function in my TetEditingController.

Comment: @Yonkee How do you _want_ to retain the paragraph structure?

Comment: @Albion47 Open to options, with the split(' ") I was taking the words in the list and putting them back in as textSpan and it retained the formating, however this doesn't, I assume because it splits on the "return". So, to answer your question, "In any way I can"

Comment: @Yonkee You can first split on returns and then split on spaces so you end up with a list of lists. Also, *Abion.